# Dynamic SOQL variable binding not working for multiple records

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, dynamic-soql, dynamic-binding

Am building a dynamic SOQL where I am using a list of strings that represent record ids, here's an example similar to my class:

```
String q = '';
q += 'SELECT Id FROM' + object;
q += ' WHERE Id IN :record_ids';
List<sObject> sobjects = Database.query(q);
```

When `record_ids` has a single Id in the list it works fine, more then one and it does not bring back any records.

I have tried creating a string based `IN` in many forms, for example:

```
record_scope += '\'' + record_id + '\',';
```

But when I look at the logs instead of `... IN ('00000000000001','00000000000002')` I get ... `IN ('00000000000001,00000000000002')` looks like `'` are subtracted for some reason.

Any help will be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Ensure your Database has records .I dont see any glitch in the code frankly .If there are records query will return.I have a link to previous post on this topic and it has even how to spilt.

Comment: There are couple hundred accounts in the org, I have tried using `.split()` and other methods with no success, when I manually construct the string like this: `database.query(... Id IN :('0001','0002','0003') ...)` it works fine. But the interesting thing is that `q += ' WHERE Id IN :record_ids';` works perfectly fine  when `record_ids` string list has only one entry, but when it has more no records are returned.

Comment: sounds like record_ids is a string which has 'a,b,c' in it, rather than a List<String>, post the code where you declare/populate the record_ids variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there was a problem with the `record_ids` list, Visualforce parameter that held all the ids was passed in as a single entry, this explains why it worked with only one entry and not with multiple.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Hi @rumdumdum,  how did you solve your problem? I'm experiencing the same problem, but with parameters I get from HTTP response. I'm saving the values from external source as List(String) and then dynamically bind that List into SOQL query. But it only works if I pass only one parameter. When I pass more than one, the query doesn't respond. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ha! I take that back :) I solved the problem with a `.split(',');` function. I took the parameters from my HTTP response, saved them as String and then I performed the split on this String and saved it as List. What a simple solution!

Answer (score 3):

You can [directly use bind variables in dynamic soql](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/elegant-way-to-convert-setid-into-string-for-dynamic-soql-in-comparison), as incredible as it sounds.

Alternatively, [the more traditional approach of quote delimiting the keyset](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4669/use-string-array-in-in-clause-in-dynamic-soql) and constructing your where clause manually. You can use the shiny [Winter'13 String.Join](http://blogs.developerforce.com/developer-relations/2012/10/68-shiny-new-apex-string-methods-in-winter-13.html) method to iterate over a list and append with a delimiter.

Comment: I think rumdumdum was already using a bind variable `q += ' WHERE Id IN :record_ids'`, but not getting the expected result.

Comment: Thanks Peter, as I mentioned, I have tried all of the above approaches. But the interesting thing is that `q += ' WHERE Id IN :record_ids';` works perfectly fine when record_ids string list has only one entry, but when it has more no records are returned in the query.

Answer (score 1):

[Elegant way to convert Set<Id> into String for Dynamic SOQL IN comparison](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/elegant-way-to-convert-setid-into-string-for-dynamic-soql-in-comparison)

Have a look at the above post.You need not even split and all

```
Map<Id,Account> accts = new Map<Id,Account>([select Id from Account]);
Set<Id> accountIds = accts.keySet();
String q = 'select id from Contact where AccountId in :accountIds';
List<Contact> cts = Database.query(q);
```

Just use the variable as demonstarted in above code .

Comment: Thanks Mohith, I have tried the above and in my case `q += ' WHERE Id IN :record_ids';` works perfectly fine when record_ids string list has only one entry, but when it has more no records are returned in the query.

Answer (score 1):

The initial approach looks good, though the code you have posted won't work as is:
* object is a reserved word
* you have no space after FROM before the object name

These I guess are only symptoms of simplifying the code for posting it here.

The code below works in my org (though these particular Ids are fake):

```
String objectName = 'Account';
List<String> record_ids = new List<String> {'001000000000001','001000000000002','001000000000003'};
String q = '';
q += 'SELECT Id FROM ' + objectName;
q += ' WHERE Id IN :record_ids';
List<sObject> sobjects = Database.query(q);
```

I'd have to assume then that it is the building of record_ids that's at fault.

You could try using this debugging code before the Database.query to verify the state of record_ids:

```
system.assert(record_ids.size()>1);
for(String item : record_ids)
    Id myId = (ID) item;
```

Comment: Thanks Steve, the code I posted was more of an example, both of your points are correct. I have tried debugging and everything looks fine, as I mentioned in my previous comments, the list works fine when there is one entry, but does not work with multiple entries.

Comment: So, to humour me, does my snipped work in your org if you run it anon? And if not, what's being logged?

Comment: Looks like there was a problem with the `record_ids` list where a Visualforce parameter that held all the ids was passed in as a single entry, this explains why it worked with only one entry and not with multiple

Answer (score 0):

Create `record_ids` as a List of Strings or Ids, e.g.

```
List<Id> record_ids = new List<Id>{
  '00000000000001',
  '00000000000002'
};
```

If you have an existing string of Ids, you can convert it an array using String.split.

Comment: `record_ids` is defined a List of Strings, but still no luck, as I mentioned above it works fine when the list has one entry and does not work when the list has more then one entry