# Passing array position as variable in dynamic SOQL

Tags: dynamic-soql

I want to pass a list position to my dynamic query, but it does not evaluate. have someone try something like this :

```
      .......
      if(selectedType == Constants.settlementTypeAutre){
        query += ' and  numm__Tech_TypeCollectif__c NOT IN( :parameters[5],:parameters[6])'; 
    }else if(selectedType == Constants.settlementTypeFournisseur){
        query += ' and  numm__Tech_TypeCollectif__c IN( :parameters[5],:parameters[8])'; 
    }
    else if(selectedType == Constants.settlementTypeClient){
        query += ' and  numm__Tech_TypeCollectif__c IN( :parameters[6],:parameters[8])'; 
    } .....
```

i don't want to create one variable by one, because i have 12 variables to put in this query. If there is no solution, then i will have to do it.

Comment: Have you tried `NOT IN : ( parameters[5],parameters[6])` ?

Comment: in my example their is only the in, but there are also this : and numm__IdEstablishment__c = :parameters[0] , how should i reference this one ? the error im obtaining is : System.QueryException: unexpected token: '['

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bind variables (`:something`) in dynamic SOQL must be a simple variable name that will still be a valid variable when the SELECT is actually executed. So:

- `:someVar` is OK
- `:someArray[3]` isn't
- `:someObject.someField` isn't
- `:someFunction()` also isn't

(all these are fine in regular `[SELECT ...]` statements, the limitation applies only for building queries as strings)

This was extensively covered in similar questions:

- [Bind variable with dotted name not working in dynamic SOQL](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8408/bind-variable-with-dotted-name-not-working-in-dynamic-soql)
- [Dynamic SOQL variable binding not working for multiple records](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5639/dynamic-soql-variable-binding-not-working-for-multiple-records)

So I'd say you should make a helper variable (Set? List?) and depending on the conditions add your params to that helper. Then you can have single

```
query += ' and numm__Tech_TypeCollectif__c IN :helper';
```

regardless of the contents.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just create map of paramethers instead of list and just use selectedType  as key?

`Map<String, String[]> paramMap;`

I have no idea what type are those values so I just used string.