# Bind variable with dotted name not working in dynamic SOQL

Tags: dynamic-soql

As mentioned in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3527/450), it's possible to use bind variables in dynamic SOQL queries.  This seems like a great way to avoid SOQL-injection, and to build a query string once but use it multiple times with different values in the variables.

I'm working on a method that returns a list of objects.  It accepts a class with multiple properties as its only parameter.  The properties of this class are used to filter the results to just the required records.  It will eventually be driven by a Visualforce component, which will be configured by querystring parameters in the URL.

I just ran into an issue where the query fails when I use dotted bind variables.  If I copy the constructed dynamic SOQL into a static query, it works fine.  This may be a bug, because in doing tests I found that `:foo.bar` would actually try to use local variable `bar`.

Here's one of my queries, which uses related custom objects.  I've stripped it down to just the part that's failing (wrapped for legibility):

```
result = Database.query('SELECT Name, Another_Object__r.Name,
     Another_Object__r.Custom_Field__c
     FROM Custom_Object__c 
     WHERE Another_Object__r.Custom_Field__c = :filter.deviceType');
```

The error reported is `System.QueryException: Variable does not exist: filter.deviceType`.  As mentioned above, the query works fine as static SOQL, just not dynamic:

```
result = [SELECT Name, Another_Object__r.Name, Another_Object__r.Custom_Field__c
FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE Another_Object__r.Custom_Field__c = :filter.deviceType];
```

It also works in this case:

```
String deviceType = filter.deviceType;
Database.query('SELECT Name, Another_Object__r.Name, Another_Object__r.Custom_Field__c
FROM Custom_Object__c WHERE Another_Object__r.Custom_Field__c = :deviceType');
```

I haven't read about this being a known limitation.  I don't know if I should be using some other syntax/notation in the query -- the dotted notation appears correct.

Time to report a bug?  Thoughts on workarounds other than creating local variables to stand in for each member of the class?

Comment: I've raised the idea [Dynamic SOQL binding expression support to match static SOQL](https://t.co/I5IYG9n6Ee) as I couldn't find an existing one.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You found the answer, dynamic SOQL is looking for your variable declaration within the scope of your method.  I don't know why it doesn't respect public properties of the class, but that is the case and your solution of setting it to a method-scoped variable should do the trick.

Comment: In this case, it's a parameter passed to the function (`filter` in my example above), which is within the scope of the method.

Comment: As the author of the initial answer: +1 to this answer. It doesn't evaluate expressions, it only binds to variables that are in scope. (if it did evaluate I would have abused it to build an eval method a while back).

Comment: @ca_peterson: OK, I think I'm starting to grasp it.  `filter` is a local variable, but `filter.deviceType` is actually an expression that requires evaluation.  I'm still picking up on the nuances of Apex classes used to emulate the C structures I'm more familiar with.

Comment: Cool. I updated my other answer to point to this question for any future readers. You might also want to mark @greenstork's answer as accepted if it got you working.

Answer (score 4):

Well some time back I wrote a blog about [Using Variables In Dynamic SOQL](http://blogforce9.blogspot.in/2012/09/using-variables-in-dynamic-soql.html), including the limitation that you cannot use dot notation in the referenced variables.