# Pulling and Searching Opportunity Contact Roles from a list of multiple opportunities

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I have a custom object with two custom connectors - one to opps and one to contacts in order to create many to many relationships to both.  To summarize I am trying to be on the main object (Demo) and be able to check for what contacts are already associated with the Demo and what contacts Could/Should be associated with the demo based on related Opportunities' Opportunity Contact Roles.

I have my custom object contact connector going to a list "Chosen Contacts" and my Opps going to a list "DemoOpps" and my available Opportunity Contact roles are also supposed to go to a list "Available contacts".  This third step "appears" to be where the breakdown occurs.  I am getting an error of Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: LIST at line 74 column 119.

The is where my string parameter comes into play.  I think the issue is that it is saying "WHERE OpportunityID = demoopps.id" because demoopps.id could have multiple ids because it is a list but I know this must be possible somehow...surely you can tell it to find all the opportunity contact roles for multiple opportunities.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Amanda

```
public with sharing class DemoContactEntryExtension {


public Demo__c theDemo {get;set;} { theDemo = new Demo__c();}
public String searchString {get;set;}
public Demo_Contact__c[] chosencontacts {get;set;} { chosencontacts = new List<Demo_Contact__c>(); }
public Opportunity[] demoopps {get;set;} { demoopps = new List<Opportunity>(); }
public Demo_Opportunity__c theDemoOpp {get;set;}  { theDemoOpp = new Demo_Opportunity__c(); }
public OpportunityContactRole[] availablecontacts {get;set;} { availableContacts = new List<OpportunityContactRole>(); }

public String toSelect {get; set;}
public String toUnselect {get; set;}
public Decimal Total {get;set;}

public Boolean overLimit {get;set;}

private Demo_Contact__c[] forDeletion = new Demo_Contact__c[]{};


public DemoContactEntryExtension(ApexPages.StandardsetController controller) {

    Id demoId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');

    // Get information about the Demo being worked on
    theDemo = [select Id from Demo__c where Id = :demoId limit 1];

    //show associated Demo Opp
    theDemoOpp = [select Id, Opportunity__c, Demo__c from Demo_Opportunity__c where Demo__c = :demoId];



    // If demo contacts were previously selected need to put them in the "selected contacts" section to start with
    chosencontacts = [
        select Id, Contact__c, Demo__c
        from Demo_Contact__c
        where Demo__c = :demoID
    ];

    // Grab associated opportunities
    demoopps = [
        select Id, Name
        from Opportunity
        where ID = :thedemoopp.Opportunity__c
    ];

    updateAvailableList();



}

// this is the 'action' method on the page
public PageReference OppCheck(){
    //if there is only one Opp we go with it and save the demo
        if(theDemoOpp.Demo__c != theDemo.Id ){
            try{
                theDemoOpp.Demo__c=theDemo.Id;
                update(theDemoOpp);
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            }
        }

        return null;

}



public void updateAvailableList() {

    // We dynamically build a query string and exclude items already in the shopping cart
    String qString = 'select Id, ContactId, OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId = \'' + demoOpps.Id + '\'';

    // note that we are looking for the search string entered by the user in the First Name OR Last Name
    // modify this to search other fields if desired
    if(searchString!=null){
        qString+= ' and (OpportunityContactRole.Contact.FirstName like \'%' + searchString + '%\' or OpportunityContactRole.Contact.LastName like \'%' + searchString + '%\')';
    }

    Set<Id> selectedEntries = new Set<Id>();
    for(Demo_Contact__c d:chosencontacts){
        selectedEntries.add(d.contact__c);
    }

    if(selectedEntries.size()>0){
        qString += ' and ContactId not in :selectedEntries';

        String tempFilter = ' and Id not in (';

        for(Id i : selectedEntries){

            tempFilter+= '\'' + (String)i + '\',';
        }

        String extraFilter = tempFilter.substring(0,tempFilter.length()-1);
        extraFilter+= ')';

        qString+= extraFilter;*/
    }

    qString+= ' order by OpportunityContactRole.Contact.Name';
    qString+= ' limit 101';

    system.debug('qString:' +qString);        
    availablecontacts = database.query(qString);

    // We only display up to 100 results... if there are more than we let the user know (see vf page)

    if(availablecontacts.size()==101){

        availablecontacts.remove(100);
        overLimit = true;
    }else{
        overLimit=false;
    }
}

public void addTochosencontacts(){

    // This function runs when a user hits "select" button next to a contact

    for(opportunitycontactrole d : availablecontacts){
        if((String)d.Id==toSelect){
            chosencontacts.add(new Demo_Contact__c(Demo__c=thedemoopp.demo__c, contact__c=d.contactid));
            break;
        }
    }

    updateAvailableList();  
}


public PageReference removeFromchosencontacts(){

    // This function runs when a user hits "remove" on an item in the "Chosen Contacts" section

    Integer count = 0;

    for(Demo_Contact__c d : chosencontacts){
        if((String)d.contact__c==toUnselect){

            if(d.Id!=null)
                forDeletion.add(d);

            chosencontacts.remove(count);
            break;
        }
        count++;
    }

    updateAvailableList();

    return null;
}

public PageReference onSave(){

    // If previously selected contacts are now removed, we need to delete them
    if(forDeletion.size()>0)
        delete(forDeletion);

    // Previously selected contacts may have new information, so we use upsert here
    try{
        if (chosencontacts.size() > 0) upsert(chosencontacts);       

    } catch(Exception e){

        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
        return null;
   }

    // After save return the user to the Opportunity
    return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
}

public PageReference onCancel(){

    // If user hits cancel we commit no changes and return them to the Opportunity   
    return new PageReference('/' + ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id'));
}


}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are only expecting one Id value. In this case, you can simply pull the first value:

```
Id demoOppsId = demoOpps.get(0).Id; // or perhaps demoOpps[0].Id;
String qString = 'select Id, ContactId, OpportunityId from OpportunityContactRole where OpportunityId = \'' + demoOppsId + '\'';
```

Also consider how your code will handle the query for theDemoOpp when demoId is actually present in multiple Demo_Opportunity__c objects.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Hraefn's answer:

You've defined demoopps as `Opportunity[]`, but in your SOQL use it as if it were a single `Opportunity`. If you want a single entry, then Hraefn's answer is a starting point, but if you want to select all of them you can bind the entire list (formatted for easy reading; should be all on one line):

```
String qString = 'select Id, ContactId, OpportunityId 
                  from OpportunityContactRole 
                  where OpportunityId in :demoopps';
```

See this [other answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3527/142) for more details.