# Dynamic SOQL How to bind date?

Tags: apex, dynamic-soql

```
soql = 'select A__c,EmplId__c, B__c,Date__c from Transaction__c Where Transaction__c.name!=null';

    if (!branch.equals(''))
    system.debug('test br1');
      soql += ' and A__c LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(branch)+'%\'';

    if (!ordernum.equals(''))
      soql += ' and B__c LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(ordernum)+'%\'';
    if (!emplid.equals(''))
      soql += ' and EmplId__c LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(emplid)+'%\'';
    if (!paybillcode.equals(''))
      soql += ' and PB_Code__c  LIKE \''+String.escapeSingleQuotes(paybillcode)+'%\'';  
    if (!wkenddate.equals(''))

    soql += ' and Date__c = wkenddate';
```

I am getting an error when binding Date.
can someone tell me what is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 8):

Two ways to accomplish this:

### Binding Statement

```
soql += ' and Date__c = :wkenddate'; // Include the ':'
```

Note: DOES NOT WORK with expressions, such as Map.keySet(), array[index], etc. Only simple primitives. You can use sets and lists, however, provided you mean to use the entire list.

### Formatting

```
soql += ' and Date__c = '+DateTime.newInstance(wkenddate, Time.newInstance(0, 0, 0, 0)).format('yyyy-dd-MM'); // Make sure it's normal SOQL formatted.
```

Comment: I have to protest that the :var format doesn't work with complex types. It absolutely does, but does not evaluate expressions. See http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/3527/60

Comment: I usually add UTC to the DateTime too: `String myStart = dateTimeVar.format('yyyy-MM-dd')+'T00:00:01.000Z';`

Comment: @ca_peterson That's really more of what I meant. You can bind to myArray, but not myArray[0], or myMap.keySet(). Anything "complex." I'll clarify with your verbiage, as I like that better anyways. We are talking about the same thing, though.

Comment: @mast0r That's correct for Date/Time fields, but the time part is implied for simple date fields and so not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 7):

If you are referencing an Apex variable in a SOQL statement, remember to prefix the variable name with `:`.

Try switching

```
 soql += ' and Date__c = wkenddate';
```

to

```
 soql += ' and Date__c = :wkenddate';
```

Answer (score -1):

Just bind using the regular syntax:

```
List<Transaction__c> = [select A__c, EmplId__c, B__c, Date__c from Transaction__c
                        where Date__c = :wkenddate];
```

The only snag with this is that the variable used for the binding must be local to the method's scope, so if `wkenddate` is a class member you'll want to do something like this:

```
Date theDate = wkenddate;
List<Transaction__c> = [select A__c, EmplId__c, B__c, Date__c from Transaction__c
                        where Date__c = :theDate];
```