# How to use DateLiteral in visualforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, date

Can anyone tell me how to use the Date Literal in apex?
My use case is I want to use Date literal as a custom picklsit.
I want to create custom picklist as follows
[image]

Please someone tell me how can I implement,

Thanks in advance,
Karthick

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like your question is regarding how to create a custom picklist in a visualforce page.  You can build the list in your control using apex or you can do so in your visualforce page.  I prefer creating the list client side.

You can do something like this:

```
<apex:page>
  <span style="font-weight:bold;">Date</span>
  <select id="dateLiteral">
    <option value="Select">Select</option>
    <option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</option>
    <option value="Today">Today</option>
    <option value="Last_Week">Last_Week</option>
    //Other options here.
  </select>
</apex:page>

<script>
  function getDate(){
    document.getElementById("dateLiteral").value;

    //Do something here with the value.
    //Perhaps invoke an actionFunction to pass value to controller or JS remoting.
  }
</script>
```

Don't forget to validate user input server side.

************* One possible working solution is below. *********************

```
<apex:page controller="testController">

  <script>
    function getDate(){
      var date = document.getElementById("dateLiteral").options[document.getElementById("dateLiteral").selectedIndex].text
      Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.testController.cons}',
        date,
        function(result, event) {
          for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML += result[i].Name + '<br/>';
          }
        }
      );
    }
  </script>

  <apex:form >
    <span style="font-weight:bold;">Date</span>
    <select id="dateLiteral">
      <option value="Select">Select</option>
      <option value="Yesterday">Yesterday</option>
      <option value="TODAY">TODAY</option>
      <option value="Last_Week">Last_Week</option>
      //Other options here.
    </select>
    <apex:commandbutton value="Submit" onclick="getDate();return false;"/>
    <div id="resultdiv"/>
  </apex:form>
</apex:page>

public with sharing class testController {

    @remoteaction
    public static list<contact> cons(string value){
       list<contact> cs = new list<contact>();
       cs = Database.query('SELECT Name FROM contact WHERE createddate = '+ value +'');
     return cs;
     }

}
```

This solution uses JavaScript remoting which is very efficient because it is stateless.  This is one of many possible solutions.  The easiest way to get your query to work is by using dynamic soql.

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_dynamic_soql.htm

Comment: My question is how to use date literal in apex

Comment: I want all the date literal as custom picklist

Comment: what is the formula for this Month,Last Month,this year,Last year,This quarter and Last quarter

Comment: Using dynamic soql is the easiest way to get your query to work since you don't necessarily have to worry about date formatting.  See my revised answer for working solution.  Please mark as best answer if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: it doesnt work because you are passing string...but in where condtion yor r checking with date datatype

Comment: I've tested and confirmed it works in my test org.  Since you're using dynamic soql comparing string with date datatype will work.  Another example of dynamic soql is here:
http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3526/elegant-way-to-convert-setid-into-string-for-dynamic-soql-in-comparison/3527#3527

Comment: but it doesnt work for me

Comment: You're using the same code I posted in my edit?  Are you getting an error in your debug log?

Comment: Nope I didnt get any error.But It doesnt display nothing

Comment: Under:  
function(result, event) {  
put the following:     
alert(result[0].Name);     This should generate an alert in your browser with the result.

Comment: how can we access the list in remote action from vfp?   

<apex:pageBlock>
            <apex:repeat value="{!cs}" var="c">
                {!c.Name}
            
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:pageBlock>

Comment: Can you post your full code?

Comment: I want to access the list in remote action from vfp

Comment: You can create an HTML table to put your results in there.  Also, you don't need the repeat tag for this method.  This line will take care of that for you.   for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++){
            document.getElementById("resultdiv").innerHTML += result[i].Name + '<br/>';
          }

Comment: No am using same controller for another page.in that page am accesing the values from this list

Comment: why we are using javascrip.. is there any other option in salesforce for making Date literal as custom picklist

Comment: Another option is to use an actionFunction to pass the user input to a method in your controller.

Comment: hmm thats sounds like good

Answer (score 0):

date literals are used in SOQL.  You would pass it to your controller to used in SOQL query.